# How to remove duplicate reference assembly for multi-project solutions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Well, I'm not familiar with C#. Here's my story:
In the VS2010 solution, there are 2 projects: Entrance, Core and Plugin. Entrance may be compiled into an exe, while the others may produce dlls. Core is added to Entrance's and Plugin's reference. Plugin is set to be compiled to plugin folder. So after compiling, the output directory contains:

```
entrance.exe
core.dll
plugin\core.dll
plugin\plugin.dll
```

How can I remove the duplicate core.dll under plugin? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about preventing `plugin\core.dll` file created when build?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes. That's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution view of the plugin project, right-click on the core.dll reference and select Properties. Set Copy Local to false to prohibit copying of the assembly to the output directory. Note this will only work properly at runtime if the referenced assembly can be found by the application. In your case it's fine since core.dll is also referenced my the application but that might not always be so.